# JScrollPane not show content after scroll in swing

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

Hi I need to display a large content(its graphical data) of data in single, so I tried following code.

```
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(3000, 300));
    canvas.setBackground(Color.blue);

    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(canvas);

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 500));
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 0));

    jsp.getHorizontalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {
        @Override
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getValue());
            repaint();
        }
    });

    add(jsp);
```

this is my MyCanvas class

```
class MyCanvas extends Canvas {

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    System.out.println("paint");
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        g.drawString(""+i, i*30, 100);
    //  g.drawLine(10, 10, 20, 20);
    }

}
}
```

but problem is that when I am scrolling window I cannot see full content as I expected it should print 100 numbers but not printed actually, can any one correct  me?

see the result here

[image: result]

Comment: have you tried layout manager?

Comment: As always, please post a decent [mcve] with your question.

Comment: Also, why are you mixing Swing (JScrollPane) with AWT (Canvas) components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you avoid mixing AWT and Swing components together (or if you absolutely **must** do this, then you have to make sure you understand the pitfalls and fully jump through all the necessary hoops.

Myself, I'd extend JPanel, I'd be sure that its preferredSize was where I want it, since this will determine how big it will be within the JScrollPane.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyScrollExample extends JPanel {
    private static final int MAX = 100;
    private MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel(MAX);

    public MyScrollExample() {
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(myPanel);
        scrollPane.getViewport().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 200));
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MyScrollExample mainPanel = new MyScrollExample();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyScrollExample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final Color BG = Color.BLUE;
    private static final Color FG = Color.YELLOW;
    private static final int WIDTH_GAP = 30;
    private static final int HEIGHT_GAP = 100;
    private int max;

    public MyPanel(int max) {
        setBackground(BG);
        this.max = max;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(FG);

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            g.drawString("" + i, i * WIDTH_GAP, HEIGHT_GAP);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        int w = (WIDTH_GAP + 1) * max; 
        int h = HEIGHT_GAP * 3;
        return new Dimension(w, h);
    }

}
```